# Can there be two precipitates in a double displacement reaction?

Tags: solubility

On one of my chemistry homework's, I am doing a double displacement reaction and the question is having me predict the products and make a net ionic equation for copper(|I) sulfate and barium acetate reacting.

$$\ce{CuSO4(aq) + Ba(OH)2(aq) -> Cu(OH)2 + BaSO4}$$

I was able to predict the products of it, but when I was starting to do the net ionic equation, I came across the problem that there were no spectator ions and I am not sure if two precipitates can form out of a double displacement reaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you were right in concluding that there are no spectator ions. How is that a problem? There is no commandment that says *"Thou shalt not have two precipitates in one reaction"*. Indeed, such double precipitations are very much possible, though rare. The most famous example is probably the formation of [lithopone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithopone).